# SignalR in python - can you host hubs?

Tags: python, signalr

I am very confused about SignalR in Python. I know it is possible to have a python client application that talks to a Server hosting a SignalR hub implemented in C#, but is it possible to implement a Server hosting a SignalR hub in python? (Without any Azure Functions integration. I just want to talk to a server hosted on my own machine(s))

Maybe my google-fu is not up to snuff, but I keep getting solutions on how to implement a SignalR client with python, but no one talks about how to implement a server.

I dont necessarily mind implementing the server in C#, I was just wondering if there was an easy way of doing it in python. (again, without any interaction with Azure Functions or other third party hosting services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SignalR protocol is well documented at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/SignalR/docs/specs.

The only server supported by Microsoft is the .NET Server. It is possible to implement your own using the linked spec.

There are a couple experimental server implementations for Go and Node at https://github.com/davidfowl/signalr-ports.